# Mysql query difference between time fields has 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

how i can check time difference between two time fields,having 24 hours

consider my table "tb1",that has following fields  id,startTime,endTime

we need find out sum of time difference between(startTime,endTime) has 24 hours with add number min as total records.that means if total difference 14.44 minutes.total count records is 4,we need add four minutes to total hours

Below query i have tired:

**Sample data**

```
Select id,StartTime, EndTime from tablename;
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | StartTime | EndTime  |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 40 | 00:00:00  | 02:59:00 |
| 41 | 04:00:00  | 05:59:00 |
| 42 | 06:00:00  | 13:29:00 |
| 43 | 15:00:00  | 18:29:00 |
+----+-----------+----------+

Select Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(EndTime, StartTime)) + 4 mintues from tablename;
```

Desired output:

```
12(in hours)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Robert The sum of those time differences is nearer to 16 hours.

Comment: @PaulCampbell how we can query the above result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you always add the number of records as minutes

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)) +  COUNT(*)) * 60) 
FROM tablename;

With your data this will return H:M:S

16:00:00

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/953c0c/21

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT round(sum((time_to_sec(timediff(EndTime,StartTime))/3600)+(4/60))) 
FROM TABLE 
limit 1;
```

Comment: This should work. 4/60 is the minutes in hour format so it can be summed.

Comment: 4 maybe variey that's based number of row